# Formating Plotly Guage Text

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have some data I'm putting on a Plotly gauge. Not sure how I managed to get a rounded number but I'd like the complete and acurate value to displayed in the text instead of just 1k, for instance my data should now say $1,001.50 but it instead says 1k.

Not too worried about the "ticks" using the k, just the text.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 0},
    value = 1001.50,
    mode = "gauge+number",
    title = {'text': "Total Donations"},
    delta = {'reference': 46000},
    gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 46000]},
             'threshold' : {
                 'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4},
                 'thickness': 0.75,
                 'value': 40000
             }}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 540,
    number = {'prefix': "$"},
    delta = {'position': "top", 'reference': 450},

    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 1}))

fig.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 1, 'columns': 2, 'pattern': "independent"},
    template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
        'title': {'text': "Donations this Month"},
        'mode' : "number+delta+gauge",
        'delta' : {'reference': 90}}]
                         }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select General for the number formatting. See [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format).

```
fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 0},
    value = 1001.50,
    mode = "gauge+number",
    number = {'valueformat':"g"},
    title = {'text': "Total Donations"},
    delta = {'reference': 46000},
    gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 46000]},
             'threshold' : {'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4}, 'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 40000}}))
```

[image]